# Code works on Console Application and not on Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, console, async-await

So I've been reading C# in Depth book by Jon Skeet, about async/await.

This is the code that works, on a Console Application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetStuff().Result);
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetStuff()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            return (await client.GetStringAsync("http://csharpindepth.com")).Length;
    }
```

However, this seems to dead-lock. The Wpf application freezes and never shows the MessageBox. I do understand it should freeze because it is running synchronously, however, I do not understand why it never continues. I have a Button, with Button_Click as the event:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetStuff().Result.ToString());
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetStuff()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            return (await client.GetStringAsync("http://csharpindepth.com")).Length;
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The duplicate does not answer why it works in Console and not in Wpf.

Comment: No, but [my MSDN article does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: What if you change it to  `var result = GetStuff().Result; MessageBox.Show(result);`. Maybe its locking inside of MessageBox...(?).